# Unable to check the text value in my table in sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsstring

I have one value which looks like this "00123-23" ,I have no idea about the datatype to be used to store in the table. So I used Text data type to store this value.But When I try to check this value,  the query is saying that there is no such value in my table, but actually there is a value. Here is my query:

```
NSString *x_accountNo;
 x_accountNo=[_substrings objectAtIndex:2];    //x_accountNo=00123-23
NSString *query_newAccount  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ACCOUNT=%@ ",x_accountNo];

BOOL recordExist_newAccount = [self recordExistOrNot_newAccount:query_newAccount];

if (!recordExist_newAccount) {

   nslog(@"no data");
}
```

Everytime I execute this statement, It is giving me no data . Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to have string inside quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ACCOUNT='%@'
```